# Solve a circuit with mesh analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

With the following circuit:

[image]

How to calculate Vo using Mesh analyses.

I have already made the following loops:

```
Loop 1: 1KΩ x l1 - 5V + 4KΩ(l1 + l3) + 4KΩ(l1 + l2) = 0
Loop 2: 3mA + 4KΩ(l2 + l1) + 2KΩ(l2 + l3) + 20V = 0
Loop 3: -20V + 2KΩ(l2 + l3) + 4KΩ(l3 - l1) + 1KΩ X l3 = 0
```

But that's as far as I got.

Comment: I managed to shorten it to -20V + 7i3 - 2i2 - 4i1 = 0

Comment: Okay let me just rewrite my entire comment. You need to solve for i3 then apply Ohm's Law to get Vo. Loop 2's equation is almost correct but you should already know i2, you shouldn't have the 3mA term in there. When you do this type of analysis, you should have voltages and currents multiplied by resistances as the things you are adding or subtracting. There are multiple ways to solve for i1 and i3 but you do have a system of equations so you can do direct substitution or with some matrix theory, you can do Gaussian Elimination.

Comment: So loop 2 should equal 3mA? I thought about Loop 1 and have it 5/1, but wasn't sure if that was correct. I'd rather not do the matrix theory. I'd rather do direct substitution.

Comment: Nope. There shouldn't be a 3mA by itself at all. Again, when you have loop equations, it should be... Loop: Voltages + (Resistances x Currents) = 0. You're adding voltages because voltage equals resistance times current. You're using KVL, are you not? Using KVL means you're adding voltages :) **_Remember:_** You should know what i2 is by simply looking at the picture. Once you figure out what i2 is, you can substitute that.

Comment: **ALSO:** Assuming your loops are going in a clockwise direction, you should check your polarity of your voltages. And the way you're adding your currents isn't correct. The only one that's right is 4kohm(i3 - i1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three meshes to work out, and one of them (the lower left) has a current assigned to it already, which is \$3\,mA\$, thus you don't have to mind the lower left mesh, which reduces your problem to 2 meshes only. 
For the lower right one we have, assuming its current to be \$I_2\$ and the upper one \$I_3\$:
 \begin{equation}
20 +  2000\cdot(0.003 - I_2) - 4000\cdot(I_2 - I_3) - 1000\cdot(I_2) = 0
\end{equation}
And for the last equation (upper mesh) yields:
\begin{equation}
4000\cdot(I_2-I_3) + 4000\cdot(0.003-I_3) - 1000\cdot(I_3) - 5 =0 
\end{equation}
We are left with 2 equations and 2 unknowns, now it's a winner winner chicken dinner!!

Solve for \$I_2\$ and \$I_3\$ to get the answers and then find \$V_o\$ from Ohm's law simply writing:

\$V_o = I_2\cdot1000\$

EDIT: Solving the equations above (currents are taken in clockwise direction) we have the outcome for \$ V_o\$ and \$ I_2\$:

\$ I_2 = 5.57 mA \$

\$ V_o = 1000\cdot I_2 = 5.57\,V\$

[image]

Comment: Inline equations are different on our site. Try doing `\$ EQUATION \$`. Also, I was hoping to help the OP understand what they were doing wrong. But they can use this as a way to check their answer so +1

Comment: @KingDuken Thank you, I'll make the necessary changes.

Comment: OH! And just like the OP, if you're assuming the meshes are clockwise, check the polarity of your voltages! :)

Comment: @KingDuken Checked, indeed I had written one of the voltages incorrectly, so thank you again.

Comment: Variables should be written as something like `\$I_2\$` and that looks like \$I_2\$

Comment: I've typed the you said but I've seen no significant changes. I don't know whaat is actually going on in my Latex here

Comment: @Iron Maiden I think you got the currents backwards. it should be  2000 ⋅ (\$I_2\$ - 3mA).

Comment: Also I think your polarity is off. Some of the equations should be positive and some negative, especially with \$I_2\$.

Comment: @Redsam121 No. The equations are correct and the currents are all assumed clockwise, and thus the results of these equations match with simulation, I'm gonna provide you the pics to clarify.

Comment: Only my equation for \$ V_o \$ was actually incorrect, where I swapped \$I_2\$ with \$I_3\$. The polarities and current assumptions are correct as shown in the simulation results.